# Why do so many English nouns have a Consonant-Vowel-Nasal ending?

Tags: phonology, morphology, english, etymology

Just a rule of thumb from my perspective (compound words are not included), such as th/t/s/z/c + /V/ + n/m:

> *T-*
>
> **-tion/-sion** (question, division, conclusion),
>
> *TH-*
>
> **-than** (leviathan),
>
> **-thon** (marathon, python),
>
> **-thm** (algorithm, rhythm),
>
> **-thom** (fathom),
>
> **-them** (anthem),
>
> *S-*
>
> **-sm** (apriorism, prism),
>
> **-san** (artisan, courtesan, partisan, ptisan),
>
> **-son**(bison, prison, season),
>
> **-som**(blossom, bosom, ransom, transom),
>
> *Z-*
>
> **-zan** (azan, bartizan),
>
> **-zen** (citizen, dozen),
>
> **-zam** (Nizam),
>
> **-zem** (chernozem, diltiazem),
>
> **-zon**(horizon, Amazon, menazon, blazon, cabezon),
>
> *C-*
>
> **-can** (florican, pecan, pelican, toucan),
>
> **-cam** (piroxicam).

Answer (score 3):

English words in -tion/-sion are nouns because this suffix comes from Latin, where it was a productive way of forming action nouns. Some of these English nouns are borrowings directly from Latin, but this suffix has become productive in English too. (Some nouns on your list are from the same origin but borrowed through French, with a change in spelling and pronunciation, e.g. benison.)

The class of words in -ism (and less frequently in -asm and -thm) comes from Greek, where -smos was a productive abstract noun formant. In this case too, -ism has become productive in English, so many words with this suffix don't have a Greek source (e.g. capitalism).

Other than these two classes, I don't think there's really a pattern here; many of the other nouns you list are very rare, and I'm sure one could come up with a few verbs with similar endings to balance them.

Comment: _-thon_ is also a productive suffix now. Very few of your words with _-z-_ are common, and several of them are arguably not English.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Proto-Indo-European language from which English derives had the ending ***-om*** in nominative for inanimate(neuter) nouns. Some words and suffixes were borrowed into English from Latin and Greek who also derived from PIE.

Other words derive from PIE words ending with -m-os and -n-os (which was a common derivational construction) with the ending -os later disappearing.

The words derived from non-IE language were often anglicized, latinized or hellenized before entering English.

For example, the -tion suffix comes from Latin, where it is inherited directly from PIE ***-ti̯om***. It is a common combination of suffixes plus nominative ending of neuter/inanimate gender. Some examples of the reconstructed PIE words with that suffix:

***a̯usti̯om*** river mouth

***plea̯ti̯om*** a kind of dress (cloak)

***tra̯nsprtea̯ti̯om*** act of carrying across

Leviathan is just a borrowing from Hebrew with little change.

Python and Marathon are borrowings from Greek where -on is the nominative ending directly derived from PIE nominative ending -om.

The suffix -ism is derived from PIE adjective suffix combination+ending ***-ismos***

Comment: As far as I can see, none of the words in the poster's list go back to PIE neuters in *-om. Latin -tion- is not a neuter suffix and isn't from *-om, and neither are the Greek words cited, which are animate nouns in -ōn.

Comment: @TKR Latin -tion directly comes to PIE -ti̯om

Comment: Latin action nouns in -tiōn- are feminine n-stems, and have nothing to do with neuter o-stems (PIE nom./acc. sg. *-om). PIE *-om gives Latin -um.

Comment: @TKR feminization of -tion is possibly a Latin-specific development. In Russian, for example, the action nouns in -ие (-ie) (<i̯om) are neuter. I know, Wikitionary postulates some misterious suffix -i̯en- for PIE, but no other source mentions it.

Comment: The Russian ending could well go back to _-iom_, but I don't see how that tells us anything about the Latin one, which is _-tion_. And at least some instances of _-ism_ go back to the Greek neuter nominal ending _-isma_.

Comment: @Anixx You're still connecting two unrelated things; there's no way an animate n-stem can come from a neuter o-stem, especially when the latter class already has an obvious reflex in Latin. The -m of *-o-m is a case ending so has nothing to do with the -n- of -tiōn-, even if there was some sound change that could connect them. Latin -tiōn- appears to be built of the feminine abstract noun suffix -ti- (cf. Gk. mētis etc.) plus the same -ōn- of Gk. marathōn, pythōn etc. (The latter also has an e-grade form, e.g. Gk. Hellēn, which maybe is what you mean by the "mysterious suffix -i̯en-"?)

Comment: @TKR how do you suppose their original forms in PIE looked? There was an -on- suffix, but it usually attached to the root, as in o̯erōn "eagle" or "e̯esōn" "autumn, harvest", and it was rare and not productive already in PIE (and even that can be a wrong reconstruction, because the -n- can represent the genetive of the l/n stem, so that the nominative was o̯erōl, which coincides with Russian "or'ol"). I know about no PIE word with the alleged -i̯en, -ti̯ōn or anything like that. Also the feminine in PIE usually ended with -a̯/-ea̯/ia̯/i̯ea̯.

Comment: @Anixx -ti- and -ōn- are both well-established IE suffixes; the Latin innovation was to combine them. There are plenty of feminine nouns in early IE languages that don't end in *-h2, so that's not a problem.

Comment: @TKR -ōn was not productive already in PIE or can you give some examples with this suffix besides what I gave? The -ti- is actually a combination of -t- and -i-.

Comment: @Anixx -ōn is still fairly productive in Greek for forming names, adjectives, etc. - see Chantraine's Formation du nom en grec ancien for examples. In any case the point for this question is that PIE *-om > Lat. -um, Gk. -on, so the suffix -(ti)ōn- in either language has no relevance here.